# Pattern with summations of roots of unity/cosines

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry

Fiddling with some number theory, I've spotted a pattern:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{\pi jm}{n+1}\right) = \begin{cases} -1, & m \ \text{ is even }\\ \ \ \ 0, & m \ \text{ is odd}\\ \ \ \ n, & m \ \text{ is a multiple of } 2n+2 \end{cases}$$

I can see why the third case holds, but does any one have any idea why the other two do?

For context, this is actually to do with sums of roots of unity and their inverses, leading to a sum of $e^{2\pi i j/(2n+2)}+ e^{-2\pi i j/(2n+2)} = 2 \cos(\pi jm/(n+1))$.

Comment: Here's the difference between \textrm{cos} (which you used initially and which I changed) and \cos: $$ \begin{align} \text{a\texrm{cos} b: } & \quad a\textrm{cos} b \\  \text{a\cos b: } & \quad a\cos b \\ \text{a\cos(b): } & \quad a\cos(b) \end{align} $$ With \cos, the spacing depends on the context; with \textrm{cos} there is no spacing. $\qquad$

Comment: Something is missing because a multiple of $2 n + 2$ is even.

Comment: @Gribouillis you're right, hang on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** hint**

Your sum is the real part of the geometric sum

$$S=\sum_{j=0}^n ( e^{i\theta})^j -1$$
with

$$\theta=\frac {m\pi}{n+1} $$
thus

$$S=\frac{1-e^{im\pi}}{1-e^{i\theta}}-1 $$